# Laravel SQL request too big

Tags: mysql, laravel, routes, prefix, tablename

**My objective**

Is to create a simple DB navigator for lambda users.
For this, i have a **side-bar** which contains all DB table_name

And at the **center of the page**, i want the data.
Here are my table names :

```
administratif
equipement
erreur
etablissement
interface_eth_routeur
interface_eth_switch
interface_ip_routeur
latence
mainteneur
routeur_arp
routeur_gsu
routeur_su
salle_visio
site
switch
switch_arp
switch_module
```

Now, there is the code :
**ROUTES.PHP**

```
Route::get('navigateur_bdd', array('uses' => 'HomeController@navigateur_bdd', 'as' => 'navigateur_bdd'));
Route::get('navigateur_bdd/{table_name}', array('uses' => 'HomeController@bdd_show_table', 'as' => 'bdd_show_table'));
```

**HOMECONTROLLER.PHP**

```
public function navigateur_bdd()
{
    $table_name = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
    return View::make('navigateur_bdd', array('which_actif' => 3, 'table_name' => $table_name));
}

public function bdd_show_table($argument = NULL) {
    $selected_table = DB::table($argument)->get();
    $table_name = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
    return View::make('navigateur_bdd', array('which_actif' => 3, 'table_name' => $table_name, 'selected_table' => $selected_table));
}
```

The first function is the main view, when the user enters in this area.

The second function is used when the user clicks on the table_name from the sidebar of the main view

**NAVIGATEUR_BDD.BLADE.PHP**

```
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">   
      <li class="well">Liste des tables</li>  
      @for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($table_name); $i ++)
          <li><a href="{{ URL::to('navigateur_bdd/' . $table_name[$i]->Tables_in_MYNET)}}">{{$table_name[$i]->Tables_in_MYNET}}</a></li>
      @endfor
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**What is hapenning now ?**
Clicking on table names such as "administratif" or "erreur" is OK

But clicking on table names which are having a prefix like "***routeur_***" **displays a blank page, with no error.**
I didn't set any prefix in the database.php because not all my tables have a prefix
How can i figure this out ?

EDIT : Some tables with prefix are working. Not all, i don't know why...Like "switch" prefix :

```
"switch"
"switch_module"
```

are working, but not

```
"switch_arp"
routeur_su
routeur_gsu
```

are working but not

```
routeur_arp
```

After investigating, i have blank page on tables having a lot a rows (110 000 for example) (tried with dd($selected_table));
So this changes the title of my question :
How can i store those 110 000 rows in a variable ?

Comment: Can you first make sure by using `dd($argument)` at the beginning of your controller that the table name gets passed correctly to the controller?

Comment: It is correct.
Each table name appears to be correct like this :
string 'interface_ip_routeur' (length=20)

Comment: And if you do the same thing but with `$selected_table`?

Comment: It don't display for the tables said before.
I get it.
The table for which it won't display the variable are the tables having 5000+rows (switch_arp have 110 000 rows)
How can i do ?

Comment: You think they have to many rows? What if you do this `DB::table($argument)->take(1000)->get()`?

Comment: It is working with 1000 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Laravels [pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) functionality.
It splits your data into pages and let's you generate links to get to each page...

```
$selected_table = DB::table($argument)->paginate(100); // how many records you wan't on one page
```

And then in your view do this to generate the links

```
{{ $table_name->links() }}
```